# How to manipulate a list in a file?

Tags: perl, replace

I want to take a text file with names on each line, such as:

Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
etc.

and prepare them for an Android array of the format:

```
<item>Name 1</item>
<item>Name 2</item>
<item>Name 3</item>
<item>etc.</item>
```

The array is very long, over 1000 items. Now, I realize that I'm essentially asking someone to write code for me. I used to be somewhat proficient in perl, but have lost touch with it.

Are there any perl gurus out there who wouldn't mind assisting me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done straight from command the line:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print "<item>$_</item>\n"' oldfile > newfile
```

If you really need it in a program:

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    print "<item>$_</item>\n";
}
```

Comment: Maybe someone will come up with a shorter version…

Answer (score 5):

Similar to @sidyll's, but shorter:

```
perl -lpe '$_="<item>$_</item>"' oldfile > newfile
```